# Probability of choosing a specific person for a team

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A team of 5 people is chosen at random from a group of 12 people, what is the probability that person *t* gets on the team

I found an answer by calculating
$1/12 + 1/11 + 1/10 + 1/9 + 1/8 ≈ .51$
But I'm not sure if that's true and I suspect there's a better way to calculate this

Comment: ehm ... How about just $5/12$ ? Notice that the method you suggest can lead to answers larger than 1 which is impossible. When you add up probabilities, you have to be extremely careful.

Comment: You only add probabilities when the events are mutually exclusive, meaning they cannot occur at the same time.

Comment: Or, if you *really* fancy binomial coefficients, you can say it is $1-\frac{11\choose 5}{12\choose 5}$ (out of all choices of $5$ people out of $12$, you refuse those that are chosen out of the $11$ people who are *not* $t$). However,  $1-\frac{11\choose 5}{12\choose 5}=1-\frac{\frac{11!}{5!6!}}{\frac{12!}{5!7!}}=1-\frac{11!5!7!}{12!5!6!}=1-\frac{7}{12}=\frac{5}{12}$

Comment: You can obtain @MattiP.'s solution by computing $$\frac{1}{12}+\frac{11}{12}\frac{1}{11}+\frac{10}{11}\frac{11}{12}\frac{1}{10}+\dots$$

Comment: You can also think of it this way: At the end of the day, 5 out of the 12 are in the team and the probability to be chosen is equal for every player. So it makes sense that the probability is 5/12.

Comment: @Patricio It is even more simple: $\frac1{12}+\frac1{12}+\cdots+\frac1{12}$. See my answer. Conditional probabilities can be avoided here.

Comment: @drhab. Of course, but I wanted to point out where their mistake was.

Comment: @Patricio Oh yes, I see now. Your comment is indeed very constructive.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{12}{5}$ ways to pick a group of $5$ out of $12$ people.

There are $\binom{11}{5}$ ways to pick a group out of all non-$t$ people.

So the asked for probability is (*not* all chosen persons are non-$t$ so) $$1- \frac{\binom{11}{5}}{\binom{12}{5}} = \frac{5}{12}$$ which sort of makes sense.

Comment: Another way:  If $t$ is on the team, then so are four of the remaining eleven people, so the probability $t$ is on the team is $\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{11}{4}}{\binom{12}{5}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there are $5$ open spots - numbered with $1,2,3,4,5$ - that must be filled up.

For spot $i$ there are $12$ equiprobable candidates and person $t$ is one of them. So the probability that person $t$ is chosen to fill up spot $i$ is: $$\frac1{12}$$

Then the probability that person $t$ is chosen to fill up one of the spots is:$$\sum_{i=1}^5\frac1{12}=\frac5{12}$$The summation is justified by the fact that we deal with mutually exclusive events.